# What is the best food bait for mice and rats?

Tags: pests, pest-control

We have some mice occasionally visiting our garden. I got some humane (catch and release) traps but not sure of the best foot bait to use in them? Some places suggest peanut butter but ideally I would like something that doesn't also attract roaches and ants. :)

Answer (score 1):

Spearmint leaves candy. The mint works as an insect repellent. The mice love the candies and are not detracted by the mint smell.

Answer (score 0):

Some answers that were incorrectly posted as comments on the question:

> In the old days we used pumpkin seeds (still in shell) – [Polypipe Wrangler](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/26164/polypipe-wrangler)

> If you position the traps correctly you won't need any bait at all. Mice prefer to move alongside a vertical "wall." Put the trap on one of their runs and the will go straight into it. On the other hand, rats are much too smart to be caught that way! – [alephzero](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/11120/alephzero)

> Inside mice round here go crazy for peanut butter. That probably varies with species. Never dealt with rats. – [Wayfaring Stranger](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/724/wayfaring-stranger)

> Are the mice eating something from your garden? If so, use the same thing in the trap. That way it won't attract any pests that weren't already being attracted. If not, Polypipe Wrangler's suggestion of pumpkin seeds in the shell seems like a good idea. They're not sugary, so they won't attract ants or roaches too much. Sunflower seeds in the shell should do the same. Or peanuts in the shell. – [csk](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/31167/csk)